# Swift imageView animation doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have code to create animation:

```
var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named:"2.png")

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {

        self.imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 500, height: 500))

        self.view.addSubview(self.imageView)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }
    }
```

But animation doesn't work. And imageView not showing.

Comment: so you want from size(100, 100) to go size(10,10) and then size(500,500) correct? first decrease size and then increase size

Comment: I edit my answer if you try the code with first duration 0 it will work

Comment: Call also `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` before the `UIView.animate()` if you want a brutal change from 100 to 10, and then an animation from 10 to 500.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Where you put those code? I mean did you put code on viewDidLoad method or anywhere else?

Comment: Depending on your task in viewDidLoad, it could take few moments to load view, in the meantime animation could start and after appearing view you see animation started from 100,100 position.

Comment: @ShamimHossain Updated question.

Comment: You should know how animation works in swift. Read this article https://www.raywenderlich.com/76200/basic-uiview-animation-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things that makes sense within an animation block (here: `UIView.animate`). Creating a newer image view is not one of them. Neither is `addSubView`.

The problem is that you are completely reassigning to your imageview variable - creating a new one within animation block.

You should create your image view and add it to your main view completely before you execute `UIView.animate.`

Animation is **changing the visible properties of your objects**, not recreating them. If you want frame change, simply do the following within animation block:

```
self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 500, height: 500)
```

You can also call `layoutSubviews()` or `layoutIfNeeded()` depending upon your constraint requirements, within `UIView.animate.`

Answer (score 3):

You should set the constraint's constant before the animation block and inside just call `layoutIfNeeded`

```
self.imageViewWidth.constant = 500
self.imageViewHeight.constant = 500

UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: This is also a solution

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {

    self.imageViewWidth.constant = 500
    self.imageViewHeight.constant = 500
    self.view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
```

To decrease and increase size you have to use the on completion handler

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.imageViewWidth.constant = 10
        self.imageViewHeight.constant = 10
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (true) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {
            self.imageViewWidth.constant = 500
            self.imageViewHeight.constant = 500
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```

if you want the decrease to start immediately change the first withDuration to 0

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Where is your problem**

Problem 1

```
imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10))
imageView.image = UIImage(named:"2.png")
```

Here, you created new instance of an image view which never has been added into viewcontroller's view stack. You should add this view into stack. These line of code doesn't have any effect on animation performance.

Problem 2

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {

    self.imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 500, height: 500))

    self.view.addSubview(self.imageView)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
}
```

You initialized another imageview and added as a subview.  This image view doesn't have any image or background color and as a result you do not see anything happending in the device screen. You should not do these stuff here. View.animate block does not need these stuff. Few things you should learn about animation. [How animation works](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76200/basic-uiview-animation-swift-tutorial)

**Solution**:
Try these lines of code instead.

```
    // initial frame
    var frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10)

    // create imageview and add this into view stack
    self.imageView = UIImageView(frame:frame)
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"2.png")
    self.view.addSubview(self.imageView)

    // set new height & width
    frame.size.width = 500;
    frame.size.height = 500;

    // animate view
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
        self.imageView.frame = frame;
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Hope, it will work!

Answer (score -1):

if you want to animate constraints than you can use this

```
self.imageViewWidth.constant = 500
self.imageViewHeight.constant = 500;              
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
     // if you are doing this in View controller then
 self.view.layoutSubviews()
     // if you are doing this in View then
     self.layoutSubviews() 
}
```

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Updated my question.